# Looking for a better method to do Quaternion differentiaton

Tags: quaternions, prediction, differentiation

I have a quaternion (4x1) and an angular velocity vector(3x1) and I call a function to calculates the differential quaternion as explained in this [web](http://www.euclideanspace.com/physics/kinematics/angularvelocity/QuaternionDifferentiation2.pdf). The code looks like this:

```
    float wx = w.at<float>(0);
float wy = w.at<float>(1);
float wz = w.at<float>(2);
float qw = q.at<float>(3); //scalar component 
float qx = q.at<float>(0);
float qy = q.at<float>(1);
float qz = q.at<float>(2);

q.at<float>(0) = 0.5f * (wx*qw + wy*qz - wz*qy);    // qdiffx
q.at<float>(1) = 0.5f * (wy*qw + wz*qx - wx*qz);    // qdiffy
q.at<float>(2) = 0.5f * (wz*qw + wx*qy - wy*qx);    // qdiffz
q.at<float>(3) = -0.5f * (wx*qx + wy*qy + wz*qz);   // qdiffw
```

So now I have the differential quaternion stored in q and then I update the quaternion by **simply adding** this differential quaternion.

Is this method suitable for predicting movement of rigid objects or is there a better method to predict quaternion with angular velocity? This works but I am not getting the expected results.

Comment: You say that you're not getting the expected results.  What seems to be going wrong?

Comment: I am using the model for tracking, and it is not stable

Comment: Is "w" vector already multiplied by "delta time"?  This equation is working properly only if "delta time" is small.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a couple things that might be going on.  You don't mention re-normalizing that quaternion.  Bad things will definitely happen if you're not doing that.  You also don't say that you multiply the delta-quaternion components by the amount of time that has passed `dt` before you add them to the original quaternion.  If your angular velocity is in radians per second, but you're only stepping forward by a fraction of a second, you'll step too far.  However, even so, since you're stepping through a discrete amount of time and trying to pretend that it's infinitesimal, weird things are going to happen, particularly if your timestep or angular velocity is large.

The physics engine, ODE, provides the option to update a body's rotation from its angular velocity as though it were taking an infinitesimal step or to update using a finite sized step.  The finite step is much more accurate, but involves some trig. functions and so is a little bit slower.  The relevant ODE source code can be seen [here, lines 300-321](http://opende.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/opende/trunk/ode/src/util.cpp?revision=1858&view=markup), with code finding the delta-quaternion [here, line 310](http://opende.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/opende/trunk/ode/src/rotation.cpp?revision=1858&view=markup).

```
float wMag = sqrt(wx*wx + wy*wy + wz*wz);
float theta = 0.5f*wMag*dt;
q[0] = cos(theta);  // Scalar component
float s = sinc(theta)*0.5f*dt;
q[1] = wx * s; 
q[2] = wy * s;
q[3] = wz * s;
```

Where `sinc(x)` is:

```
if (fabs(x) < 1.0e-4) return (1.0) - x*x*(0.166666666666666666667);
else return sin(x)/x;
```

This allows you to avoid the divide-by-zero problem and is still very precise.

The quaternion `q` is then pre-multiplied onto the existing quaternion representation of the body's orientation.  Then, re-normalize.

---

Edit--Where this formula comes from:

Consider initial quaternion `q0` and final quaternion `q1` which results after rotating with angular velocity `w` for `dt` amount of time.  All we're doing here is changing the angular velocity vector into a quaternion and then rotating the first orientation by that quaternion.  Both quaternions and angular velocities are variations on the axis-angle representation.  A body that is **rotated** from its canonical orientation by `theta` around unit axis `[x,y,z]` will have the following quaternion representation of its orientation: `q0 = [cos(theta/2) sin(theta/2)x sin(theta/2)y sin(theta/2)z]`.
A body that is **rotating** `theta/s` around unit axis `[x,y,z]` will have angular velocity `w=[theta*x theta*y theta*z]`.  So, in order to decide how much rotation will happen over `dt` seconds, we first extract the magnitude of the angular velocity: `theta/s = sqrt(w[0]^2 + w[1]^2 + w[2]^2)`.  Then we find the actual angle by multiplying by `dt` (and simultaneously divide by 2 for convenience in turning this into a quaternion).  Since we need to normalize the axis `[x y z]`, we're also dividing by `theta`.  That's where the `sinc(theta)` part comes from.  (since `theta` has an extra `0.5*dt` in it from being the magnitude, we multiply that back out). The `sinc(x)` function is just using the Taylor series approximation of the function when `x` is small because it's numerically stable and more accurate to do so.  The ability to use this handy function is why we didn't just divide by the actual magnitude `wMag`.  Bodies that are not rotating very fast will have very small angular velocities.  Since we expect this to be pretty common, we need a stable solution.  What we end up with is a quaternion that represents a single step time step `dt` of rotation.

Comment: There is no sense to check sin(x)/x close to zero, cause sin(x) strongly equal to x near zero. Just check if not equal zero.

Comment: @minorlogic It's true that sin(x) is approximately equal to (x) when x is small.  However, floating-point inaccuracies mean that if you divide one really small number by another really small number, you have no idea what you'll get back.  It will depend on how the rounding worked out.  Moreover, when x is small but non-zero, you avoid doing a trig function without losing any accuracy with the Taylor series method; consequently, this runs much faster.

Comment: You are wrong in both assumptions. Floating point operations precision not dependent from its value. The number of used bits for mantisa is always same. The sin(x) function become EXACT sin(x)->x near zero and don't introduce additional roundoff errors. To check it , you can simply test code with taylor series and compare (bit to bit) with sin(x)/x. Near zero it strongly equals to 1.0

What about speed, on modern processors sin(x) can be processed on CPU and can be faster than manual taylor expansion.

Comment: This seems like an interesting discussion on `sinc`. I've just tried Julia's implementation for some small floating point numbers, and the direct `sin(x)/x` implementation gives the right result: `1.0`. However, if the implementation of `sin` isn't ideal, I wonder if this could lead to errors / instability? In that case, checking for proximity to 0 might be reasonable defensive programming. Regardless – very useful write up on obtaining a quaternion from orthogonal angular velocities.

Answer (score 0):

There is a metod with very good trade-off between **speed and  accuracy** how to **increment a quaterniom representing rotational state** ( i.e. integrate differential equation of rotational motion) by small vector increment of angle `dphi` ( which is vector angular velocity `omega` mulptipliad by time step `dt` ).

The **Exact (and slow) method of rotation of quaternion by vector**:

```
void rotate_quaternion_by_vector_vec ( double [] dphi, double [] q ) {
  double x = dphi[0];
  double y = dphi[1];
  double z = dphi[2];

  double r2    = x*x + y*y + z*z;
  double norm = Math.sqrt( r2 );

  double halfAngle = norm * 0.5d;
  double sa = Math.sin( halfAngle )/norm; // we normalize it here to save multiplications
  double ca = Math.cos( halfAngle );
  x*=sa; y*=sa; z*=sa;  

  double qx = q[0];
  double qy = q[1];
  double qz = q[2];
  double qw = q[3];

  q[0] =  x*qw + y*qz - z*qy + ca*qx;
  q[1] = -x*qz + y*qw + z*qx + ca*qy;
  q[2] =  x*qy - y*qx + z*qw + ca*qz;
  q[3] = -x*qx - y*qy - z*qz + ca*qw;
}
```

The problem is that you have to compute slow functions like `cos, sin, sqrt`. Instead you can obtain considerable speed gain and reasonable accuracy for small angles ( which is the case if the time step of your simulation is reasonable small ) by approximating `sin` and `cos` by taylor expansion expressed just using `norm^2` instead of `norm`.

Like this **Fast method of rotation of quaternion by vector**:

```
void rotate_quaternion_by_vector_Fast ( double [] dphi, double [] q ) {
  double x = dphi[0];
  double y = dphi[1];
  double z = dphi[2];

  double r2    = x*x + y*y + z*z;

  // derived from second order taylor expansion
  // often this is accuracy is sufficient
  final double c3 = 1.0d/(6 * 2*2*2 )      ; // evaulated in compile time
  final double c2 = 1.0d/(2 * 2*2)         ; // evaulated in compile time
  double sa =    0.5d - c3*r2              ; 
  double ca =    1    - c2*r2              ; 

  x*=sa;
  y*=sa;
  z*=sa;

  double qx = q[0];
  double qy = q[1];
  double qz = q[2];
  double qw = q[3];

  q[0] =  x*qw + y*qz - z*qy + ca*qx;
  q[1] = -x*qz + y*qw + z*qx + ca*qy;
  q[2] =  x*qy - y*qx + z*qw + ca*qz;
  q[3] = -x*qx - y*qy - z*qz + ca*qw;

}
```

you can increase accuracy by doing half o angle which 5 more multiplications:

```
  final double c3 = 1.0d/( 6.0 *4*4*4  ) ; // evaulated in compile time
  final double c2 = 1.0d/( 2.0 *4*4    ) ; // evaulated in compile time
  double sa_ =    0.25d - c3*r2          ;  
  double ca_ =    1     - c2*r2          ;  
  double ca  = ca_*ca_ - sa_*sa_*r2      ;
  double sa  = 2*ca_*sa_                 ;
```

or even more accurate by an other spliting angle to halfs:

```
  final double c3 = 1.0d/( 6 *8*8*8 ); // evaulated in compile time
  final double c2 = 1.0d/( 2 *8*8   ); // evaulated in compile time
  double sa = (  0.125d - c3*r2 )      ;
  double ca =    1      - c2*r2        ;
  double ca_ = ca*ca - sa*sa*r2;
  double sa_ = 2*ca*sa;
         ca = ca_*ca_ - sa_*sa_*r2;
         sa = 2*ca_*sa_;
```

---

**NOTE:** If you use more sophisticated integration scheme than just verlet (like Runge-Kutta ) you **would probably need a differential of the quaternion**, rather than the new ( updated ) quaternion.

this is possible to see in the code here

```
  q[0] =  x*qw + y*qz - z*qy + ca*qx;
  q[1] = -x*qz + y*qw + z*qx + ca*qy;
  q[2] =  x*qy - y*qx + z*qw + ca*qz;
  q[3] = -x*qx - y*qy - z*qz + ca*qw;
```

it could be interpreted as multiplication of the old (not updated ) quaternion by `ca` ( cosine of half angle ) which is approximativelly `ca ~ 1` for small angles and adding the rest (some cross interactions). So the differential simply:

```
  dq[0] =  x*qw + y*qz - z*qy + (1-ca)*qx;
  dq[1] = -x*qz + y*qw + z*qx + (1-ca)*qy;
  dq[2] =  x*qy - y*qx + z*qw + (1-ca)*qz;
  dq[3] = -x*qx - y*qy - z*qz + (1-ca)*qw;
```

where term `( 1 - ca ) ~ 0` for small angles and could be sometimes neglected ( basically it just renormalize the quternion).

Answer (score 0):

Simple conversion from "exponential map" to quaternion. (exponential map equal to angular velocity multiplied by deltaTime). Result quaternion is delta rotation for passed deltaTime and angular velocity "w".

```
Vector3 em = w*deltaTime; // exponential map
{
Quaternion q;
Vector3 ha = em/2.0; // vector of half angle

double l = ha.norm();
if(l > 0)
{
    double ss = sin(l)/l;
    q = Quaternion(cos(l), ha.x()*ss, ha.y()*ss, ha.z()*ss);
}else{
    // if l is too small, its norm can be equal 0 but norm_inf greater 0
    q = Quaternion(1.0, ha.x(), ha.y(), ha.z());
}
```